# disk cache mode: "write back" vs "write through" in iscsi context

Tags: cache, iscsi

I have a few iscsi drives connected to a debian. The iscsi drive (sde,sdg, one for each path) and the multipath device (dm-25) have the "write_cache" property (/sys/devices/virtual/block/dm-XX/queue/write_cache or /sys/block/sdX/queue/write_cache ) set as "write back". I can set the writecache mode to "write through".

I am trying to understand what is the meaning of "writeback" and "writethrough" in the iscsi context. Does the iscsi driver offers some kind of local caching?

If I set this to "writethrough", does this mean that an iscsi write command will be ACKed if the command is succesfully communicated over the iscsi TCP connection?

Thanx!

Comment: This would be drive caching. Drives where data integrity is a concern (databases) usually have write caching disabled (write through). SCSI also implements commands to control this (Forced Unit Access or FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING). https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/sql-server-on-linux-forced-unit-access-fua-internals/ba-p/3199102

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to understand what is the meaning of "writeback" and "writethrough" in the iscsi context. Does the iscsi driver offers some kind of local caching?

It might. There also might be some caching at the file-system level, with the same implications.

*Write through* means that a write operation is synchronous - the data is put in cache and written to disk. Once that has finished control returns to the file system or the application - that way it always knows which piece of data has made it to permanent storage.

*Write back* is an asynchronous write operation - data is put in cache, a write-to-disk operation *is queued* and control immediately returns to the file system/application. There's no way to know whether all data has made it to permanent storage. It eventually should but if the power fails in between or if there's a hard crash it might not.

*Write back* is somewhat dangerous with local storage (so we use battery-backed cache) but it's much more dangerous with network storage - because there is so much more that can go wrong. Without proper setup, *write back caching* can seriously damage or even destroy a good journaling file system.

A proper setup includes:

- redundant power for servers
- redundant power for storage
- redundant UPS
- redundant network paths
- good monitoring, so any failure doesn't go unnoticed with all that redundancy